# Hide hidden files in dialog boxes in Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer

I've checked the option "Don't show hidden files, folders and drives" in the folder options so I can't see hidden files and folders. In Windows Explorer, it works fine, but in open file dialog boxes in some programs, such as Qt Creator, I can still see the hidden files and folders. In other programs, such as Word, I can't see hidden files or folders.

To illustrate my problem, I've included three screenshots. The first one is from Windows Explorer, the second one is from an open file dialog box in Qt Creator and the third one is from an open file dialog box in Word. I haven't changed any settings or created or deleted any files between the screenshots.

[image: namnlöss]

[image: namnlös]

[image: namnlö]

As you can see, the hidden folders are hidden as they should in Windows Explorer and in Word, but not in Qt Creator.

Why does it do this? How can I hide hidden files and folders in the open file dialog boxes of all programs?

Comment: This would happen because they are using their own dialog instead of the win32 dialog

Comment: This is one of the first times I've seen an external program showing hidden files.